# Polling API every x seconds with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polling

I have to monitoring some data update info on the screen each one or two seconds.
The way I figured that was using this implementation:

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(()=> this.getItems(), 1000);
      }
    
      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.timer = null;
      }
    
      getItems() {
        fetch(this.getEndpoint('api url endpoint'))
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => this.setState({ items: result }));
      }
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: This is a way to do it, but it's inefficient and will overload your server when you scale your app. If you use a socket connection, you can be notified when messages arrive, which will be much more efficient

Comment: I just have the REST API to consume... how can I make this "pooling" in a properly way?

Comment: It depends on what technology you have in your server. You should do some reading on how web sockets work, There is an article here http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets but there are plenty of resources around to play with

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Well, since you have only an API and don't have control over it in order to change it to use sockets, the only way you have is to poll.

As per your polling is concerned, you're doing the decent approach. But there is one catch in your code above.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timer = setInterval(()=> this.getItems(), 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.timer = null; // here...
}

getItems() {
  fetch(this.getEndpoint('api url endpoint'))
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({ items: result }));
}
```

The issue here is that once your component unmounts, though the reference to interval that you stored in `this.timer` is set to `null`, it is not stopped yet. The interval will keep invoking the handler even after your component has been unmounted and will try to `setState` in a component which no longer exists.

To handle it properly use `clearInterval(this.timer)` first and then set `this.timer = null`.

Also, the `fetch` call is asynchronous, which might cause the same issue. Make it [cancelable](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch) and cancel if any `fetch` is incomplete.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It would be nice if you demonstrated how to make the changes you propose.

Comment: Careful with async calls using setInterval() as it will call even if it's waiting for the API to respond. A safer call would be using setTimeout() with recursion.

Comment: A working example of @GustavoGarcia's comment is added here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63134447/5618143

Answer (score 65):

Although an old question it was the top result when I searched for React Polling and didn't have an answer that worked with Hooks.

> ```
> // utils.js
>
> import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
>
> export const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
>
>   const savedCallback = useRef();
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     savedCallback.current = callback;
>   }, [callback]);
>
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     function tick() {
>       savedCallback.current();
>     }
>     if (delay !== null) {
>       const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
>       return () => clearInterval(id);
>     }
>   }, [delay]);
> }
> ```

Source: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

You can then just import and use.

```
// MyPage.js

import useInterval from '../utils';

const MyPage = () => {

  useInterval(() => {
    // put your interval code here.
  }, 1000 * 10);

  return <div>my page content</div>;
}
```

Comment: How do we cancel useInterval ? I mean stop the polling on any condition

Comment: Setting the time to 0 cancels the timer

Comment: how to make this in typescript?

Comment: Typescript NPM package for this hook: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@use-it/interval

Comment: How to cancel the timer once I get the response I wanted after polling? Tried to add `0` in delay. It makes continuous calls to the API.

Comment: Pass in `null`. In mine I also treat 0 as null to avoid DDOSing my APIs on accident.

Answer (score 11):

You could use a combination of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

`setInterval` would fire the API call every 'x' seconds irrespective whether the previous call succeeded or failed. This can eat into your browser memory and degrade performance over time. Moreover, if the server is down, `setInterval` would continue to bombard the server not knowing its down status.

Whereas,

You could do a recursion using `setTimeout`. Fire a subsequent API call, only if the previous API call succeed. If previous call has failed, clear the timeout and do not fire any further calls. if required, alert the user on failure. Let the user refresh the page to restart this process.

Here is an example code:

```
let apiTimeout = setTimeout(fetchAPIData, 1000);

function fetchAPIData(){
    fetch('API_END_POINT')
    .then(res => {
            if(res.statusCode == 200){
                // Process the response and update the view.
                // Recreate a setTimeout API call which will be fired after 1 second.
                apiTimeout = setTimeout(fetchAPIData, 1000);
            }else{
                clearTimeout(apiTimeout);
                // Failure case. If required, alert the user.
            }
    })
    .fail(function(){
         clearTimeout(apiTimeout);
         // Failure case. If required, alert the user.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@AmitJS94, there's a detailed section on how to stop an interval that adds onto the methods that GavKilbride mentioned [in this article](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

The author says to add a state for a delay variable, and to pass in "null" for that delay when you want to pause the interval:

```
const [delay, setDelay] = useState(1000);
const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true);
  useInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, isRunning ? delay : null);

    useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }

    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
```

Definitely read the article to get a better understanding of the details -- it's super thorough and well-written!

Answer (score 2):

As Vasanth mention, I preferred to:

- use setTimeout to measure the time between the end of the last request and the beginning of the next one
- make the first request straight away, not after the delay
- inspired by the answer from @KyleMit https://stackoverflow.com/a/64654157/343900

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export const useInterval = (
  callback: Function,
  fnCondition: Function,
  delay: number,
) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef<Function>();
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let id: NodeJS.Timeout;
    const tick = async () => {
      try {
        const response =
          typeof savedCallback.current === 'function' &&
          (await savedCallback.current());
        if (fnCondition(response)) {
          id = setTimeout(tick, delay);
        } else {
          clearTimeout(id);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };
    tick();
    return () => id && clearTimeout(id);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [delay]);
};
```

**WORKS**: Using *fnCondition* inside which can be a condition based on the response from the last request.

```js
//axios-hooks
const {
    data,
    isLoadingData,
    getData,
} = api.useGetData();

const fnCondition = (result: any) => {
    const randomContidion = Math.random();
    //return true to continue
    return randomContidion < 0.9;
  };
useInterval(() => getData(), fnCondition, 1000);
```

**DOES NOT WORK**: Passing *delay* as *null* to stop *useInterval* like this **does not work for me**
with this code: https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-09-23-recursive-settimeout-with-react-hooks/

(You might get the impression it works, but after a few starts/stops it breaks)

```js
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true);
  const handleOnclick = () => {
    setIsRunning(!isRunning);
  };

  useInterval(() => getData(), isRunning ? 1000 : null);
```

```
  <button onClick={handleOnclick}>{isRunning ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}</button>
```

Sum up: I'm able to stop useInterval by passing fnCondition, but not by passing *delay=null*

Comment: Do you know why you save the callback in a ref ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example using hooks in function component and this will refresh your data in a set interval.

```
import React from 'react';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  let [jokes, setJokes] = useState('Initial');

  async function fetchJokes() {
    let a = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
    let b = await a.json();
    setJokes(b.value);
  }

// Below function works like compomentWillUnmount and hence it clears the timeout
  useEffect(() => {
    let id = setTimeout(fetchJokes, 2000);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  });

  return <div>{jokes}</div>;
}
```

or, you can use axios as well to make the API calls.

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("Loading.....");

  function fetchData() {
    axios.get(`https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random`).then((response) => {
      setState(response.data.value);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hi there!");
    let timerId = setTimeout(fetchData, 2000);
     return ()=> clearInterval(timerId); 
  });

  return (
    <>
      This component
      <h3>{state}</h3>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. You should never use `setInterval` for polling purposes as you can quickly get into race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple, full solution, that:

- Polls every X seconds
- Has the option of increasing the timeout each time the logic runs so you don't overload the server
- Clears the timeouts when the end user exits the component

  ```
   //mount data
   componentDidMount() {
       //run this function to get your data for the first time
       this.getYourData();
       //use the setTimeout to poll continuously, but each time increase the timer
       this.timer = setTimeout(this.timeoutIncreaser, this.timeoutCounter);
   }

   //unmounting process
   componentWillUnmount() {
       this.timer = null; //clear variable
       this.timeoutIncreaser = null; //clear function that resets timer
   }

   //increase by timeout by certain amount each time this is ran, and call fetchData() to reload screen
   timeoutIncreaser = () => {
       this.timeoutCounter += 1000 * 2; //increase timeout by 2 seconds every time
       this.getYourData(); //this can be any function that you want ran every x seconds
       setTimeout(this.timeoutIncreaser, this.timeoutCounter);
   }
  ```