# Wait for AJAX response and halt execution for few minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling an external API where it will create a file(zip file) based on the requirements, but to create a file it will take 3-5 minutes.
my code was before

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'myPage.php',
        data: entries,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

It will create a file in the backend but it does not send a response.
After sometime I see the 504 error in the console.
In the external API, only after the file is created it will return a JSON response.

So, I implemented the jquery promise

```
function functABC(entries, requrl) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      url: requrl,
      data: entries,
      success: function(data) {
        resolve(data) // Resolve promise and go to then()
      },
      error: function(err) {
        reject(err) // Reject the promise and go to catch()
      }
    });
  });
}

functABC(entries, requrl).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

The above code returns Null and in the external API I see the following error

```
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Is the above jquery promise code correct or should i need to add something?

An answer would be helpful

Comment: This is server side problem. Are you using Apache or Ngnix

Comment: @BriscoPeasAristide: Thanks for the response.
 i am using Nginx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208031/polling-until-getting-specific-result

Comment: Using a Promise in this case has no difference on execution time or anything. It's just uses jQuery's ajax.

Comment: Apparently, this error comes from Cloudflare if the request takes longer than 2 minutes to respond
will look into it. I may need to run it as a background task because it takes that long