# Creation of polling with axios and React

Tags: reactjs, axios, polling

I am trying to implement axios poling with React. I am expecting the get request to return a certain value but because it's async method I have to wait for it.

React method:

```
 getInformationMessageOnSubmit = () => {
     getInformationMessage().then(output => 
     this.setState({message: output})
  };
```

And I also have an axios request in a different file:

```
const getInfo = () => {
  return axios.get('url')
    .then(output => output)
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}


export const getInformationMessage = sealId => {
  setInterval(() => getInfo(sealId), 1000);
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [polling api every x seconds with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140764/polling-api-every-x-seconds-with-react)

Comment: Yes I was following this example but it didn't work for me

Comment: Can you please share your implementation so far in a CodeSandbox sample?