# useEffect keep fetching my data if I add state in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

when I added eventList into my useEffect in an array like this:

```
  const getEvents = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/events/event/${teamId}`);

    setEventList(res.data.Events);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, [eventList]);
```

It just keep fetching data non stop

but if I don't put eventList in there my page just fetch it one time and when I click to another component is will gone

Added Component:

Calendar.js:

```
const Calendar = (props) => {
  const { teamId } = props;
  const events = [];
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([]);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState("");

  const getEvents = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/events/event/${teamId}`);

    setEventList(res.data.Events);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, []);

  const handleChangeAccordion = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  const handleChangeCalendar = (value) => {
    const currentDate = moment(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    setDate(currentDate);
    const currentEvents = events.find((event) =>
      moment(currentDate).isSame(event.date, "day")
    );
    setEventList(currentEvents ? currentEvents.events : []);
  };

  const [showCalendarCard, setShowCalendarCard] = useState(false);

  const addEvent = () => {
    setShowCalendarCard(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="calendar-tab">
      <div className="event-view-container">
        <div className="event-date">
          <p className="event-date-monthday">{moment(date).format("D")}</p>
          <p className="event-date-weekday">{moment(date).format("dddd")}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="event-list">
          {eventList.map((event, index) => (
            <div>
              <Accordion
                key={`event-${index}`}
                square
                expanded={expanded === `event${index + 1}`}
                onChange={handleChangeAccordion(`event${index + 1}`)}
              >
                <AccordionSummary>
                  <div className="event-list-item-header">
                    <span className="timestart">
                      {moment(event.timestart, "HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm A")}
                    </span>
                    <span className="dash">-</span>
                    <span className="timeend">
                      {moment(event.timeend, "HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm A")}
                    </span>
                    <span className="title">{event.title}</span>
                  </div>
                </AccordionSummary>
              </Accordion>
              <div className="event-list-item-content">
                <div className="header">
                  <span className="announcements">Announcements</span>
                  <div className="plus">
                    <ControlPoint />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="content">{event.description}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="calendar-view-container">
        <div className="event-calendar-container">
          {!showCalendarCard ? (
            <div>
              <EventCalendar
                className="event-calendar"
                formatShortWeekday={(locale, date) =>
                  moment(date).format("dd").charAt(0)
                }
                tileClassName={({ date }) => {
                  if (events.find((x) => moment(x.date).isSame(date, "day"))) {
                    return "highlight";
                  }
                }}
                onChange={(value) => handleChangeCalendar(value)}
                nextLabel={<NavigateNext />}
                prevLabel={<NavigateBefore />}
              />
              <div className="add-event">
                <ControlPoint onClick={addEvent} />
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <CalendarCard
              setShowCalendarCard={setShowCalendarCard}
              teamId={teamId}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

When I click to another day in calendar it will disspear my list of events.

Here is the photo of my project:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using a timer of some sort rather than putting React into an infinite loop.

Comment: @DBS how can I do that?

Comment: There are some decent questions that cover this sort of thig, e.g. [Polling api every x seconds with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140764/polling-api-every-x-seconds-with-react)

Answer (score 2):

Your useEffect is depending on `eventList` to change and by calling that function you are changing `eventList`, If you want to send the request only once then this solution will do

```
const Calendar = (props) => {
  const { teamId } = props;
  // const events = [];
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([]);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState("");

  const getEvents = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/events/event/${teamId}`);

    setEventList(res.data.Events);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, []);
```

Having an empty dependant list will only trigger the function once so change

```
useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, [eventList]);
```

To this

```
useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, []);
```

Comment: But if it’s call only once when I change to another component it will disappear

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the component?

Comment: I just edited it. So when I click to another day in calendar the data will gone and when I click back to the date it created it still gone

Answer (score 1):

Its stuck in a loop because your `useEffect` callback has the side-effect changing it's own dependency (`eventList`).

Basically instead of resetting the event list you fetched from the API, memoize the filtered list

e.g.

```js
const filteredEventList = useMemo(() => {
  return eventList.filter((event) =>
      moment(date).isSame(event.date, "day")
    )
}, [date, eventList])
```

and then use this filtered event list in your render

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: Well you need to organize you code a little better. Avoid hitting the API whenever the user inputs something. I'll edit with a little more detail.

Comment: Updated, have a look.