# What is the most optimized way to make a request every 10 seconds using react/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Every time the request finishes loading I need to wait 10 seconds and fetch the data. So far I use 2 useEffects one to verify if the data is ready and the other to loop the counter until it gets to 0. I was wondering if there is a better way.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      timer = setInterval(() => setCounter(value => value - 1), 1000)
    }
  }, [loading])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer)
      refetch()
      setCounter(10)
    }
  }, [counter, refetch])
```

Comment: Why use an extra counter at all? Just `setInterval(refetch, 10 * 1000)`.

Comment: Optimized for what? Memory usage? CPU cycles?

Comment: one better way might be instead of polling: sockets.
via - socket.io if the server is local. if it's not local and you're calling an external API then you are probably stuck with polling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Polling API every x seconds with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140764/polling-api-every-x-seconds-with-react)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you might be intersted in [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/). It provides React hooks for data fetching, and has options for [polling at intervals](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-interval), as well as other things (revalidate on focus, or manual revalidation for example).